# parsing date 01-01-0001 with jodatime

Tags: java, date, jodatime

If this function is passed an invalid date and an IllegalFieldValueExcption is thrown I would like to return a default date of `0001-01-01`. But when the code below is ran the date that is created in `defaultDate` is `0001-01-02`, which is wrong. Does anyone see anything i'm doing wrong?

```
public Date unmarshal(String string) {    
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatter(null, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").getParser());
    Date defaultDate = DateTime.parse("0001-01-01", fmt).toDate();

    try {
        return formatter.parseDateTime(string).toDate();
    }
    catch (IllegalFieldValueException e) {
        return defaultDate;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I updated the first two lines with these and it is working perfect now, thanks!

```
Chronology chrono = GJChronology.getInstance();
Date defaultDate = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01, 10, 0, 0, 0, chrono).toDate();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is because the **default [chronology](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_chronology.html) in Joda-Time is ISO**. This calendar system is the same as that used by business in the majority of the world today. ***The ISO system is unsuitable for historical work before 1583 as it applies the leap year rules from today back in time*** (it is a proleptic calendar).

So you shoudn't use a `defaultDate` before 1583 with ISO Chronology. If you need to use such Date, you have to use a different chronology in Joda-Time.

Comment: +1.  "to return a default date of 0001-01-01" smells bad (jodatime or not). perhaps better to return `null` instead?

Comment: 0001-01-01 is the 'low date' used for our system, I didn't create this, it is just what it needs to be.

Comment: That is also a quite common date value for non-null low dates in the Oracle database